# R code to Provide progress on code execution

Tags: r, optimization

So, I have a task that needs to be performed on a list of objects (30 total objects). I used to have this coded as individual objects, and would run it one at a time. But after some StackExchange feedback I have moved on to lists. But, when I execute the code so it starts going through the list and completing the desired task, I have no idea what the progress is. I only see the red stopsign in the RStudio GUI, so I have no idea if the computer is hung up, or what object in the list it is currently working on.

Has anyone tried to create some sort of Feedback code chunk, where you will get some sort of feedback when an object in the listed is completed?

Editing for more details

I have this list

```
sizes <- list(
n1.6<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
n7.8<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
n9.10<-c(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
```

Which actually has 30 objects but the 3 above are an example

and I have this function

```
strata_eq <- function(n_vec){
  sample_means <-matrix(rep(0,80000), nrow=16, ncol=5000)
  for(i in 1:5000){
    sample <- strata(data[,c(1,23)], "stream", n_vec, method="srswor")
    sample <- data[sample$ID_unit,]
    stream_means <- with(sample, tapply(avg.RPD, stream, mean)) 
    sample_means[,i] <- c(unlist(stream_means))
  }
  return(sample_means)
}
```

I then would like to pass this function to the list, so that the function is applied to every object in the list.

```
rates <- lapply(sizes, function(x) strata_eq(x)
)
```

However, this takes really long, and I was hoping there was some sort of code that would help provide some progress on the execution. Maybe just something that tells me what object is completed in the list, or which one it is working on...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include in your code, a `print` function with the time passed. It should be enough to allow you to estimate the remaining time if your function is equivalent on all the objects.

At the beginning of your code:

```
ptm <- proc.time()
```

In your function:

```
strata_eq <- function(n_vec){
  sample_means <-matrix(rep(0,80000), nrow=16, ncol=5000)
  for(i in 1:5000){
    sample <- strata(data[,c(1,23)], "stream", n_vec, method="srswor")
    sample <- data[sample$ID_unit,]
    stream_means <- with(sample, tapply(avg.RPD, stream, mean)) 
    sample_means[,i] <- c(unlist(stream_means))
  }
  print(proc.time() - ptm)
  return(sample_means)
}
```

I then would like to pass this function to the list, so that the function is applied to every object in the list.

```
rates <- lapply(sizes, strata_eq)
```

May I suggest you as well some trick to tighten your function:

- Create a table equal to data[,c(1,23)] before the beginning of the function
- replacing the for by a `*ply*` function and convert your result into a matrix later on. Easily achievable using `rbindlist`, for example.
- Which lead to : use the package `data.table`

Comment: The `apply` and `dplyr` are function which allow to execute a function on all the elements of a given list, vector, matrix rows or columns, etc. Could you add more details to your question, as it is not clear what you are achieving.

Comment: Could you expand on how to tighten up the function, I am not sure how do write the code for what you are suggesting..

Comment: Also, I added the proc.time code you as suggested. It returns the below values and I am not sure what they represent.

 user  198.03; system 0.03 ;elapsed 258.51

Comment: Hit `?proc.time` in your console. In general, the r help is well made and most of your answers could be found within the r help.